# PHP Dependency Injection is a good design, but I can't get Intellisense from IDE?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

For example:
My DI is like the following:

```
$container['user'] = function ($c) {
    return new \App\Service\User($c);
};
```

And I use it in my controller like this:

```
public function login(Request $request, Response $response) {
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
        $user = $this->container['user'];

        if($user->login($username, $password)) {
            return $response->withRedirect('/');
        }
        // ...
}
```

When I write my code, I can't get the intellisense of the **login** method(However, it exists indeed). It is a common problem, anyone good advice?

Comment: Name of the IDE??

Comment: the best PHP IDE: PhpStorm

Comment: Lol the best?  That's what you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [@var](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html) annotation to add a type of a variable:

```
public function login(Request $request, Response $response) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    /**
     * @var \App\Service\User $user
     */
    $user = $this->container['user'];

    if($user->login($username, $password)) {
        return $response->withRedirect('/');
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: best answer, you save my day